# Do the expressions "front-rear direction" , "left-right direction ", "top-bottom direction" sound strange?

Tags: adjectives

I have found these expressions in translation made by non-native speakers, for example, "the engine power is transmitted in the front-rear direction of the car".  I want to know alternative expressions.

Comment: How "mathematical" should the writing be? If writing technically there may already be problems with "transmitting power" and you should perhaps be talking about the direction of "force" instead. Could you give a little more context please.

Comment: Example sentence: "In this type of car, an engine is located on the front side relative to (compared to) a transmission in the front-rear direction of a car. "

Comment: I think the translations have several grammar or logical issues, but basically perhaps "the engine power is transmitted *in a front-to-rear direction*".